Downloading a excel file and need to reload the page once the download is completed
I have a webpage to download a excel in vb.net. The excel is generated from multiple xml files. There is no problem in the download of excel it is working fine. Once the download is completed I need to reload the entire page. The code i use to download the excel file is
With HttpContext.Current.Response
.ClearContent()
.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=a.xls;")
.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
.Charset = "UTF-8"
.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
.Write(oXMLDataMS.XSLTransform(sPath, oArgs))
.Flush()

Once after the download got completed i tried to reload the page using Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) but it provides an error like http header is already sent. So, we can't redirect. But I need to reload the page after excel got downloaded.
I tried to add reload using Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) but it didn't worked and provided error http header is already sent.

Is this WebForms?

@Magnus Yes, it is a webforms. I found some more info. when i use response.Addheader it is moving the response to download the excel file and after that the response is not working.

Instead of doing a postback and then writing the the response stream. Have hyperlink or button with href=yourDownloadPage.aspx and write to the response stream on that page,

Sure, I have added a xsl file for the front end with code <xsl:attribute name="href">xsl:textDownload.aspx?Path=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$XmlFileName"/>xsl:text&download=true&</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$Random"/></xsl:attribute> when the user click on the download hyperlink it is now downloading the excel file. now i need to contact with download.js file to call one function from download.aspx.vb file. Can you please suggest some code to add the javascript file in download.aspx.vb file.
